# How to call style pane without double click in the style area in MS Word 2003

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to call the style pane without double clicking in the style area window.

I have used the below method to call `formattingproperties` but i can't call directly style pane.

```
Sub FormattingProperties()
   Dialogs(wdDialogFormatFont).Show
End Sub
```

I want to show style pane below to the user using a macro

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 2003 installed so I can't test this for you, but...

Look in the Word VBA Help files for the WdWordDialog enumeration, if you haven't found it already. There are a number of entries for styles. I *think* what you're looking for may be one of these:

```
wdDialogFormatStyle
wdDialogFormatStylesCustom
```